# Get Product Image with specific Role in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, image, role

Does anyone know how to get the image with a specific role from a product. For example, I've created a new role called 'global' and assigned one of the product images to that role. How can I get that image ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For getting custom product image role at any place using product object like below way,**

You can just get product image role using below way,

```
$_products->getData('global');
```

If product with **`global`** role is assigned at that time you got global image value in above query.

Clear cache and check.